# gstreamer0.10 video sink without X

Tags: linux, video-streaming, cross-compiling, gstreamer

My system is composed of:

- RPi3
- Rasbian Jessie Lite
- gstreamer0.10 with base/good/bad/ugly plugins installed
- cross-compiled Qt5.6.1

The goal is to use gstreamer as QtMultimedia backend. It works for audio but it cannot find a suitable video sink.
I searched in the documentation and in the Debian packages but I cannot understand where to find the video sink based upon OpenGL!

EDIT:

tried with gstreamer-1.8.2 (messages are translated in English)

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! glimagesink
Set the pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: unable to pause pipeline.
Got context from element 'sink': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstGLImageSinkBin:glimagesinkbin0/GstGLImageSink:sink: Failed to connect to X display server
Further debug information:
gstglimagesink.c(833): _ensure_gl_setup (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstGLImageSinkBin:glimagesinkbin0/GstGLImageSink:sink
Set pipeline to NULL ...
Execution of free on pipeline...
```

Why it tries to connect to X-server?

Comment: I think there was no OpenGL video sink of hoary past of 0.10 .. In 1.6 the opengl stuff is much stable (or even 1.8) - I recommend to try that :) there is glimagesink

Comment: As far as I know gstreamer 1.0 in Debian Jessie is at 1.4.4, so I'm afraid I need to compile it from sources.

Comment: Ok, just try how it works.. it may be stable enough

Comment: I edit the original questions because I tried with gstreamer-1.x but it doesn't work because glimagesink looks for X server!

Answer (score -1):

This might come a bit late, but both of these work in a virtual console on my laptop using GStreamer 1.9.90:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! intervideosink # internal video sink

gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! aasink # ascii-art video sink
```

None of them tried to connect to X.